# Sole employee of US company. Any issues working remotely in Peru on tourist visa?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, work, peru, taxes

Here's my situation:

- created a company in the US (an LLC)
- the only employee for the company
- occasionally hire temporary contractors.
- staying in Peru for 6 months on their extended tourist visa
- will earn money through my company while in Peru
- the money will go into the company's US bank account

What legal/visa/tax issues would I face?

The more I look into this, the more confused I get  Maybe it's simpler than I think?

Comment: Whatever the answer is, I doubt it's simpler than you think.  Certainly some countries such as the US and the UK take a very dim view of this sort of thing and give very little leeway.  Others, at least Canada, allow it explicitly.  I suppose some officially prohibit it but are generally lax about it.  I don't know what attitude Peru adopts on this question, so I'm looking forward to an answer from someone who does.

Comment: It might be simple but not good news... some countries don't allow you to do any work at all (whether you're in a company of 1 or 100,000) if you're there on a tourist visa, though my impression is that enforcement is often lax.  I don't know what Peru's rules are though, and also look forward to an answer from someone who does.

Comment: I don't know the answer, however generally you're on a lot thinner ground if any income comes from local (Peruvian) companies, even if routed through a US shell corporation.

Comment: I would think you'd need to consult your tax attorney to be safe.